# What are all of Mercurial's built in commit identifiers?

Tags: mercurial

I'm looking for easy ways to move around to different commits, sometimes within a branch (and not necessarily from the latest commit). For example, I'd want a way to always get to the previous commit:

```sh
# move to commit before current commit
hg checkout -r ~.1
```

or move to the top of the branch

```sh
hg checkout tip
```

But I can't figure out things like how to move to the next commit (i.e. the one above the current commit, the negation of `~.1`). `hg` seems to have built in ways of referencing these things (e.g. `tip` (latest commit), `.` (current commit), and `.~N` (N-th previous commit)), but are there any others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You have to re-read `hg help revsets` carefully and a) build (if needed) b) use these revsets in hg commands

- If you want to use "~" notation, you have to use *proper format* of revset `hg log -r ".~1"` for immediate parent and remember "only 1-st parent is evaluated" (mergesets, f.e, have two parents)

> ```
> "x~n"
>   The nth first ancestor of x
> ```

- Top of *named branch* (branch head) isn't `tip` (tip - ltest commit in repo, can be in another branch), but branchname per se for `hg up`
- With "x~n" revsets you can use negative numbers also: for n < 0, the nth *unambiguous descendant* of x.

Comment: Thanks, `hg help revsets` was just what I was looking for!